# Brightway2 : How can I increase verbosity?

Tags: python, architecture, environment-variables, brightway

```
from brightway2 import *

projects.set_current("default")

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    filename="log_import.txt",
                    filemode="a",
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

logging.debug("La fonction a bien été exécutée")
logging.info("Message d'information général")
logging.warning("Attention !")
logging.error("Une erreur est arrivée")
logging.critical("Erreur critique")

e38cutoff = SingleOutputEcospold2Importer("/home/360.1.466-BRIGHTWAY2/Database/ecoinvent 3.8_cutoff_ecoSpold02/dataset")
```

Hi,
I'm gonna import Ecoinvent and I wanted to know how I can increase verbosity in order to know every single action of BW2 and how I can send potential errors in a file .text or .log that I can further inspect. Is this method correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently don't log very much in the [different strategies used to import `ecospold2`](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/master/bw2io/strategies/ecospold2.py). In the short term, you can redefine these functions to add for logging, and then change the attribute `SingleOutputEcospold2Importer.strategies` after instantiation. In the longer term, you are welcome to submit a pull request to add more thorough logging. For example, the [Ocelot](https://ocelot.space/) project did extensive logging in [each transformation function](https://github.com/OcelotProject/Ocelot/tree/master/ocelot/transformations).